# Populate Tree using data from ArrayCollection

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, tree, components

Let's say I had an ArrayCollection like this:

```
        public var ac:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection([
            {item:"dog", group:"Animals"},
            {item:"orange", group:"Fruits"}, 
            {item:"cat", group:"Animals"},
            {item:"apple", group:"Fruits"}
            ]);
```

How would I create a Tree component in Flex 3 that uses the groups as nodes, with the appropriate items listed under each node?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `labelField` property of the Tree to dictate which property you want to be the label for each node.

In your example, this would give you a single-level `Tree`:

```
<mx:Tree id="tree" dataProvider="{ac}" labelField="item" />
```

These links should help you out:

- [Array as a Data Provider in a Tree](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/03/using-an-array-as-a-data-provider-in-a-flex-tree-control/)
- [Filter a Tree with an ArrayCollection](http://www.kalengibbons.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/filtering-a-flex-tree-using-an-arraycollection/)

---

**Edit:** the `ArrayCollection` you created contains objects, each of which match groups with items.  If you want to use a `Tree`, you need to think hierarchically, from top to bottom.

The top-most objects will be your "groups", comprised of objects representing the "items."  In your `ArrayCollection`, each index will need to be an `Object` which, in turn, contains any nested children.  Please note: each object **must** have their nested children specified in a property named "children."

For example:

```
{name: "Animals", children: new ArrayCollection([ {name: "Dog"}, {name: "Cat"} ])}
```

This `Object is thus structured hierarchically:

Object: Animals
|
|-- children
     |
     Dog
     |
     Cat

From here, the `Dog` and `Cat` objects could also have a `children` property, pointing to yet another `ArrayCollection`.  Does this make sense?

Note how each object contains the same identifier.  In this case, I used "name" for the label which will be displayed in the `Tree`.  You can also use the `labelFunction` property to define a function which returns a `String` and thus can determine what the label for a given node is at run-time.

I took your `ArrayCollection` and bundled it into a simple application which displays it as a `Tree`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        [Bindable] public var ac:ArrayCollection= new ArrayCollection([
             { name: "Animals", children: new ArrayCollection([ {name: "dog"},    {name: "cat"}])},
             { name: "Fruits",  children: new ArrayCollection([ {name: "orange"}, {name: "apple"} ])}]);

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:Tree dataProvider="{ac}" labelField="name" />
```

Comment: I tried that but that only lists the items.  I tried setting labelField="group" but that only listed the groups (didn't make them into clickable nodes with the items as children). I will check out the links you posted.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, you don't have a nested object structure (i.e. objects embedded w/in objects).  As a result, your "tree" will look flat because it only has a single level.  The examples I posted show how to nest objects w/in objects so you get the hierarchical view.

Comment: Do they really show how to generate a hierarchical structure from flat/grouped data? The first link just seems to (artificially) add "children" nodes to the array, while the second starts off by constructing a hierarchically structured ArrayCollection. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a hierarchical `ArrayCollection` with children node in it from a flat `ArrayCollection`.

[Here is a link on Adobes cookbooks.](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Creating_Hierarchical_ArrayCollection_out_of_Flat-17426.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have used this way and works for me: [a link](http://manikmagar.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/flex-tree-and-groupingcollection/)!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
creationComplete="windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event)" xmlns:local="*"
width="318" height="400">
<s:layout>
    <s:VerticalLayout/>
</s:layout>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.CollectionEvent;
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        protected function windowedapplication1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            refreshTree();    
        }

        private function refreshTree():void{
            gc.refresh();
            myTree.dataProvider = gc.getRoot();
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>

    <s:ArrayCollection id="arcData">
            <local:TestItem year="2009" month="Jan" label="Jan Report 1"/>
            <local:TestItem year="2009" month="Jan" label="Jan Report 2"/>
            <local:TestItem year="2009" month="July" label="July Report 1"/>
            <local:TestItem year="2009" month="July" label="July Report 2"/>
            <local:TestItem year="2010" month="Feb" label="Feb Report 1"/>
            <local:TestItem year="2010" month="Feb" label="Feb Report 2"/>
            <local:TestItem year="2010" month="Dec" label="Dec Report 1"/>
            <local:TestItem year="2010" month="Dec" label="Dec Report 2"/>
    </s:ArrayCollection>

    <mx:GroupingCollection2 id="gc" source="{arcData}">
        <mx:grouping>
            <mx:Grouping>
                <mx:fields>
                    <mx:GroupingField name="year"/>
                    <mx:GroupingField name="month"/>    
                </mx:fields>
            </mx:Grouping>
        </mx:grouping>
    </mx:GroupingCollection2>
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:Tree id="myTree" dataProvider="{gc.getRoot()}" labelField="GroupLabel" width="100%" height="100%">

</mx:Tree>

</s:Application>
```